# Galois Theory - $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I'm studying Galois Theory using Pinter's Book of Abstract Algebra. Quoting the book, questions are followed:

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is an extension of degree 4 over $\mathbb{Q}$, so by Theorem 1, there are four automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ which fix $\mathbb{Q}$: Now,  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is the root field of $(x^2 – 2)(x^2 − 3)$ over for it contains the roots of this polynomial, and any extension of containing the roots of $(x^2 – 2)(x^2 − 3)$ certainly contains $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$.

Since every element of  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is of the form $a + b\sqrt{2} + c\sqrt{3} + d\sqrt{6}$, these four automorphisms (shall call them ε, α, β, and γ) are the following:

$a + b\sqrt{2} + c\sqrt{3} + d\sqrt{6} \xrightarrow{ε} a + b\sqrt{2} + c\sqrt{3} + d\sqrt{6}$
$a + b\sqrt{2} + c\sqrt{3} + d\sqrt{6} \xrightarrow{α} a - b\sqrt{2} + c\sqrt{3} - d\sqrt{6}$
$a + b\sqrt{2} + c\sqrt{3} + d\sqrt{6} \xrightarrow{β} a + b\sqrt{2} - c\sqrt{3} - d\sqrt{6}$
$a + b\sqrt{2} + c\sqrt{3} + d\sqrt{6} \xrightarrow{γ} a - b\sqrt{2} - c\sqrt{3} + d\sqrt{6}$

If $K$ is an extension of $F$, the automorphisms of $K$ which fix $F$ form a group.

Question:
1) How is $\sqrt{6}$ root of $(x^2 – 2)(x^2 − 3)$?

2) Wonder if someone could explain to me how does the four automorphisms ε, α, β, and γ mapping work? and how it is that $α \circ β = γ $?

I tried to do a little more reading on my own. Came across this pdf article, http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/galoisappn.pdf

3) How is it that the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$
is  $X^4 - 10X^2 +1$?

Thank you!

Comment: $\sqrt{6}$ isn't a root of that polynomial. But it is in the field generated by the roots of that polynomial. To see what happens when you compose automorphisms, remember this. Since the field we're talking about is generated by $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$, any automorphism $\sigma$ is entirely determined by $\sigma(\sqrt{2})$ and $\sigma(\sqrt{3})$. So to track compositions, just look at what happens to those two elements. Your last question can be broken into two parts. First is checking that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ is a root of that polynomial. Second, that that polynomial is irreducible.

Answer (score 2):

Answers to your questions...

1. $\sqrt 6$ is not a root of $(X^2- 2)(X^2- 3)$, but it is an element of the field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3)$ since $\sqrt6 = \sqrt2\sqrt3$.
2. An automorphism of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3)$ is completely determined by where $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt3$ is sent. Moreover it must send $\sqrt2$ to a root of its minimal polynomial $X^2-2$, i.e., either $\sqrt2$ or $-\sqrt2$ (and similar for $\sqrt3$). For example, the automorphism of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3)$ defined by sending $\sqrt2\mapsto -\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt3 \mapsto \sqrt3$, ends up sending $\sqrt6 \mapsto -\sqrt6$ (since it's a ring homomorphism) and corresponds to your $\alpha$ above. Similar for the other maps...
3. As noted in the comments, you can check that $\sqrt2 + \sqrt3$ is a root of that polynomial and that it is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

   Where did it come from? One way: First note that the element $\sqrt2 + \sqrt3$ is not fixed by any nonidentity automorphism of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3)$ (check!), so $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2 + \sqrt3) = \mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3)$ by Galois theory; since the latter is a degree 4 extension of $\mathbb Q$, it follows that the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt2 + \sqrt3$ over $\mathbb Q$ is degree 4 and its roots are the Galois conjugates of $\sqrt2 + \sqrt3$, i.e. $\epsilon(\sqrt2+\sqrt3), \alpha(\sqrt2 + \sqrt3), \beta(\sqrt2 + \sqrt3), \gamma(\sqrt2 + \sqrt3)$ in your notation. Thus the minimal polynomial factors as $$(X - \epsilon(\sqrt2+\sqrt3))(X-\alpha(\sqrt2 + \sqrt3))(X-\beta(\sqrt2 + \sqrt3))(X- \gamma(\sqrt2 + \sqrt3))$$ in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3)$ which you can check equals $X^4 - 10X + 1$.